# Is it correct to use the word 'made' in the present continuous or simple present tense?

Tags: tense, present-tense, present-continuous, present-simple

I am studying the English tenses and came across the following quiz:

> Fill in the correct verb form: PRESENT SIMPLE or PRESENT PROGRESSIVE.
>
> The delicious chocolate is ____ by a firm in Switzerland. (MAKE)

The correct answer was 'made'.

So far, I have never seen the second (or third?) form of the verb used in the present simple and present progressive. Is this a good solution, and is there some exception I haven't heard of? This doesn't made any sense.

The quiz is available at this link: https://www.english-grammar.at/online_exercises/tenses/present-simple-progressive6.htm

Comment: Second or third form?? make, made, made. Passive: is made, present tense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sentence is in the passive voice, where the simple present is *is made* and the present progressive is *is being made.*